# Recognizing multiple named entity types on a noun phrase using NLP

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, opennlp, uima

I'm currently using OpenNLP with UIMA to label words in a sentence. It's important that a single word can be labelled more than once. For example `David Cronenberg` should be labelled as `director` and `person`.

I know the training process is implemented correctly because I have a custom model file and when all sentences with one of the labels is removed from the model file the other label is detected.

I would preferably be able to continue to use OpenNLP to double label words. Is there a way to do this? If not is this possible with another library such as Stanford CoreNLP.

The code that gets the labels is below:

```
List<NamedEntity> entities = JCasUtil.selectCovered( NamedEntity.class, aConstituent );
    if ( !entities.isEmpty() ) {
        // is never more than 1
    }
```

And some sample training data is below (there are hundreds of lines similar to this.)

```
<START:person> David Cronenberg <END> directed <START:film> Crash <END> .
<START:director> David Cronenberg <END> directed <START:film> Scanners <END> .
```

Comment: Reach out to the developers of OpenNLP. You may find help here, but you'll likely find more there. If it's open source then look into the code - you may not only find your answer there, but a solution as well.

Answer (score 2):

Train separate classifiers for the different types of named entities, e.g. one for `person` and one for `director`. Then add multiple OpenNlpNamedEntityRecognizer components to your pipeline, each configured with one of your models.